# Вывод первой картинки Gallery Modx

Tags: изображения, modx, revo

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в ModX Revo изпользуя плагин Gallery вывести первую картинку альбома, при условии, что альбом выводится так:
Есть галерея, в ней подразделы, выведенные через pdoMenu, и в чанке подраздела чанк для слайдера-карусели.

Код чанка вывода подразделов:

```html
<li[[+classes]]>
  <div>
    <h2>[[+pagetitle]] </h2>
    <div id="slider">
      <div id="slider_box">
        [[pdoMenu? &parents=`[[+id]]` &tpl=`albumsrow`]]
      </div>
      <div id="nav_slider">
        <div id="left_nav"></div>
        <div id="right_nav"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </li>
```

Код чанка pdoMenu выше:

```html
<li><div class="img"><a href="[[+link]]">
  <div>
     [[!pdoResources?
        &sortby=`id`
              &class=`galItem`
              &limit=`1`
               &sortdir=`Asc`
               &resources=`79, 81`
             ]]
       </div>
         <div>
      <span class="date">[[+publishedon:date=`%d.%m.%Y`]]</span>
     <br>
     <span>[[+pagetitle]]</span>
  </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</li>
```

Сделал, как видите, через pdoResources, он берет первую картинку из первого альбома, и ставит для каждого элемента списка.

В общем, нужна помощь: может есть другие способы вывести первую картинку из альбома, без разницы из альбома Gallery или страницы, на которой альбом вызывается.

У меня есть плагин для выдергивания первой картинки из [[*content]], но как его отредактировать на получение картинки не из контента не знаю.